# What maven package is StreamingListener in?

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark project with these dependencies:

```
// spark dependencies
implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-core_${scalaVersion}:${sparkVersion}"
implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-sql_${scalaVersion}:${sparkVersion}"
implementation "org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_${scalaVersion}:${sparkVersion}"
```

However, when I try to type `import org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.StreamingListener` in my code, it shows an error, saying that it can't find that class.

So, I guess I didn't include the right dependency, which dependency contains this class?

Answer (score 0):

It's in project "Spark streaming":

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming